# Don't generate db but map to existing tables

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

We'd like to use model first to generate clean EF models for our application but instead of having the model generate a new db schema we'd like to then manually do a table mapping within the entity to an existing database table or tables. Is there a mechanism for this?

Answer (score 1):

Sure is.

This is called **Entity Framework Code-First** and this is a [good tutorial to help getting you started](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx).

The idea is that you create some POCO classes seperate to your Repository/Database class. In this Repository/Database class, you define all the relationships between your POCO's. Fortunately, Entity Framework has a number of *conventions* which you can leverage off, which means you might not need to define *every* relationship and rule.

Eg. If your class is called `User`, then it will assume (by default, unless you override this) that the database table is called `Users` and the primary key identity field in the POCO will be `UserId` and the same in the database table.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question, but when you use the wizard to create a new Entity data model, the first step allows you to "Generate from database", just point it to your existing DB. You can then cut out the tables you don't want and/or modify the table mappings manually. There's also the option to pick and choose which tables you want represented in your model in the first place.

Comment: In an entperrise level application when you have 750 tables and 500 procs etc you want to generate clean models without having to import your whole database. Cutting it apart and even viewing it are very problematic. So what the user is asking is a really valid question in enterprise level applications.  You want to define clean models that you can then attach to appropriate tables in the db.  From what I can tell you cannot use model first to do this unfortunately but I am actually researching the same issue now for a large enterprise level application.

Answer (score 0):

I also looked for this option using EF Model first with EF 4.0.   I also wanted to start with a small clean model because we have a huge enterprise level application in which we cannot import everything into one edmx because it is not even viewable due to the scale of our database.

So we wanted to consider model first as an option to build smaller, cleaner models and then map them to our existing tables in our db.

This is what we learned.

Model first generates the db schema that will go into an "existing db".  It is somewhat misleading initially because people think that it creates a new db. It does not actually create the db itself.  The db must exist and then model first generates the t-sql scripts that will go into the db.

It generates these scripts in a new .sql file in your project which you can then view or send off to a dba if you have one.

It will generate these scripts as CREATES for tables assuming that your tables do not exist.

So, as an example, if you created a "Customer" entity in the model, it will generate a script (*.sql) file containing CREATE TABLE T-sql to create the customer table for your customer entity that you can then run on an existing sql database.

So this is what it is designed to do, generate clean tables for a new model basically.

Does this mean that you can't use it at all if your tables already exist?  No, you can use it. You just wouldnt run the Create scripts that it generates.  I don't believe it was really designed for this but we tested this and it did work.

Where you may run into additional problems with model first, and a limitation we have found, is that because model first is designed to generate new db schema, you cannot map to existing stored procedures. This was a problem for us and so we eliminated model first as an option for our architecture.

We are reviewing code first and db first right now as options for an enterprise level system and right now we are leaning toward code first at this time. Code first allows you to create small, manageable contexts that you can work with and this seems very beneficial in a large enterprise level application.